# Which economic model and variables should I use to investigate the impact of sentimental shocks in central bank statements on investment?

Tags: regression, central-banking, investment

0

I am currently working on a research project that aims to investigate the impact of sentimental shocks in central bank statements on investment in the economy. I am looking for guidance on selecting an appropriate economic model to analyze this relationship effectively.

Which economic model would be most suitable for studying the influence of sentimental shocks in central bank statements on investment?

What are the key variables that I should include in my analysis to measure sentimental shocks in central bank statements?

In addition to the main variables of interest, what other variables should I consider controlling for to ensure the reliability and accuracy of the results?

Any insights, recommended literature, or methodological tips related to this research topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

I tried to find out the sentimental score of all the statements of Central Bank of Pakistan. Now I am a bit confused, that how can I use these scores in econometric model to check, how these sentimental shocks conveyed in the documents of Central Bank of Pakistan, impact investment in the economy of Pakistan.

Comment: you are asking quite a lot of varied and broad questions, could you please consider narrowing your question down and split it in multiple questions?